# CURLOPT POSTFIELDS not attatching data to HTTP Request

Tags: php, curl, http-request

I've been trying to send something via HTTP request, using the CURLOPT POSTFIELDS and the data doesn't seem to transfer. Am I missing something?

```
        function sendTestCase($caseArgs){
        try{
            $ch = curl_init();
            $sendData = http_build_query($caseArgs);
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sendData);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8888/testrail/index.php?/miniapi/add_case/');  
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:"));

            curl_exec($ch);
        }
        catch (HttpException $ex){
            echo $ex."<-Exception";
 }

 curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `$caseArgs`?

Comment: what is in caseargs and why don't you simply pass it in as an array?

Comment: It is an array. I need it to be passed as a POST argument because that is what the API calls for. Also, the post argument needs to have URL encoding too... This has been frustrating for me to say the least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSTFIELDS is perfectly capable of accepting an array and curl will do the url-building for you. As it stands now, you're passing in a string to curl (which happens to contain your form values), but not passing in a field name, so curl is sending out a bare string. Try this instead:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $caseArgs);
```